# Обновление значения в словаре или сохранение множества словарей в одном словаре

Tags: python, база-данных, tkinter, dict, value

Ребята, можете помочь с пониманием - сама не могу разобраться.
Хочу сохранять информацию полученную от пользователя в один файл через `Shelve` по нескольким сферам деятельности: Спорт, Наука и т.д.
У меня получается общий словарь с этими ключами, в которых должны быть значения в виде словарей. Вот так:

```
database['Спорт'] = {'Теннис': ['Майкл', 'Канада', 'М', 1090]}
```

Потом я каждую категорию вытаскиваю в `Treeview`.
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как обновлять именно ключ и добавлять в него **несколько** словарей. То есть пользователь вносит информацию - создаётся словарь и добавляется в существующий ключ. Помогите, как это возможно? То что есть сейчас - это все время замена уже существующего значения у ключа... Руки опускаются...

Comment: Для этой задачи лучше подойдет простенькая БД типа sqlite нежели словари

Comment: Я делаю не правильно получается?((

Comment: Да нет. Если задачу выполняет, значит делаете правильно. Не расстраивайтесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать словарь, где в качестве значения используется список словарей. Доступ к отдельному словарю - по индексу.
Альтернативный вариант - словарь словарей, тогда доступ к отдельному
словарю - по ключу.

```
dct: dict = dict(list())
dct['Sport'] = [
    {'Теннис': ['Майкл', 'Канада', 'М', 1090]},
]
dct['Sport'] .append({'Шашки': ['Си', 'Китай', 'М', 1070]})
print(dct) # {'Sport': [{'Теннис': ['Майкл', 'Канада', 'М', 1090]}, {'Шашки': ['Си', 'Китай', 'М', 1070]}]}
print(dct['Sport'][1]) # {'Шашки': ['Си', 'Китай', 'М', 1070]}
```

Comment: Владимир, вы мой спаситель! Я правда даже не догадалась об этом. Список в словаре, это же так просто! :)